# How to tell what command opens an application?

Tags: command-line, application

It happens every now and then that there's an application installed in my system which I don't know how to run from the command-line.

To find out, I usually Google or search the output of `lsof` (not always successfully) after running the application from the GUI.

There has to be an easier way. What is it?

Comment: Do you have a specific example of this?

Comment: I just did it with [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) @Kusalananda After I installed it I forgot the name of the executable file and have been launching it from the GUI. To find out how to launch it from the shell, I ran the app, and ran `lsof | grep browser` and hoped to find it easily, which I did.

Comment: I edited my question to hopefully make it clear as I don't think an example is necessary for my question. If it's still unclear, please let me know how so that I can fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applications which you can start from your desktop environment are described by [`.desktop` files](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec/), which are stored in `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications` (strictly speaking, [the corresponding XDG directories](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/basedir-spec/), but those are the default settings). Given an application name, as shown by your desktop environment, you can look for it in those files and find the corresponding `Exec` line.

To do this, you can use GUI menu editors such as GNOME’s Alacarte or [MenuLibre](https://bluesabre.org/menulibre/), or search on the command line.

Alacarte (“Main Menu” in GNOME) shows all available applications, and the properties of each entry show the corresponding command:

[image: Alacarte screenshot showing the launcher properties for “Users”]

In a terminal window, this “Users” application can be found using

```
grep -l Name.\*=Users {/usr,~/.local}/share/applications/*.desktop |
xargs -r grep Exec=
```

This shows

```
Exec=gnome-control-center user-accounts
```

and true enough,

```
gnome-control-center user-accounts
```

on the command line opens the corresponding panel.

For DB Browser, you’d run

```
grep -l "Name.*=DB Browser" {/usr,~/.local}/share/applications/*.desktop |
xargs -r grep Exec=
```

In some cases the `Exec` line will have additional arguments, *e.g.* `%f`; those are placeholders for arguments such as files.

Comment: There are also GUI `.desktop` file editors/viewers.  Some desktop systems provide simple access to them from the desktop and from menus, as a "Properties" setting on a context menu.

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks.